# Confidence interval and hypothesis-test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, confidence-interval

This is the text of my problem

> One standard test have been used many years in a class. The test can
>   give a max of 100 points. The sum can be considered as normal
>   distributed. μ=85,σ=25 Make a 95% confidence interval for the sum.

[μ−1.96∗σ,μ+1.96 * $\sigma$]

this is what i came up with.. is that right?

Next question is:

> One year the mean sum is 88.5 (n = 25 students). is there a reason to
>   believe that $\mu$ has increased(from the previous problem)? Do a
>   thesis test to find this out using a = 0.05.

So I'm not sure how i should do this. I'm a bit confused about thesis test and confidence interval. I need some help so i can get myself on the right track. At this point I'm stuck. If the first problem is correct, i just replace the values (mean with $\mu$ and 1.96 with 1,645) and see if the values are greater than the $\mu$ from the previous problem..?

Comment: Please add 'self-study' tag

Comment: Could you provide additional details: Where are you stuck? What have you tried? What is not clear for you in this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first observation is correct.

For the second, the hypothesis test is:
$(Obs-H_0)/\sigma$ for a Normal distribution (attention that here you have less than 30 observations and you *cannot* use the Normal distribution but the Student distribution.)

The previous stands to center and normalize your test such that you can use the tables.

As it is a one-sided test (you are asked if the mean statistically *increased*), you have to use the critical value pertaining to a 10% two-sided test for a Student distribution. Note that here you used the Normal distribution.